# Send Keys is not working on a login container

Tags: c#, selenium, protractor

I am trying to automate logging into our application using Protractor w/ Selenium (C#).  I know the proper way to do this is as such:

```
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId));
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId)).Clear();
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId)).SendKeys(inputText);
```

My problem is that my code finds the element in the first line but then breaks when I try to do either the Clear() or the SendKeys() giving me this error:

```
unknown error: cannot focus element

(Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

One more thing.  When I place a `Click()` rather than a `Clear` or `SendKeys` it works so I know I am looking at the correct frame.  Has anybody dealt w/ something similar and know a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cannot focus element` error usually happens when you try to send keys or issue a `clear()` method on a non-input element. Check that your by `inputTextId` id locator actually matches the `input` element.

Also, see if the desired element is the only one having this id.

Comment: Thanks!  There was an element hidden on the page that was almost identical to what I was trying to type into.  I ended up using both Class and Id in my Send Keys method.

Answer (score 1):

As exception clearly says textbax needs focus before entering value and you can do it using `Click()`, which is absolutely correct. One thing more you can try for focus directly from `SendKeys` as :

```
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId)).SendKeys(Keys.ENTER, inputText);
```

**Note** :- I'm suggesting if you are doing some action with the element on same page, always make a habit to store the element into a variable reference instead of finding element again and again and do needful action.

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

can you please try the following:

```
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId));
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId)).SendKeys(Keys.TAB);
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId)).Clear();
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId)).SendKeys(inputText);
```

OR:

```
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId));
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId)).SendKeys(Keys.TAB);
_ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inputTextId)).SendKeys(inputText);
```